# How to put a Wrap widget in a Column widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**What I want:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mo64.png)

```
child: IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const [
              Red(),
              Green(),
            ],
          ),
          const Align(
            child: Yellow(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Blue(),
      const PurpleWrap(),
    ],
  ),
),
```

**What I got:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzVGR.png)

How can I achieve what I want?

Also can I achieve it without using **IntrinsicWidth**/**Stack**?

Comment: Not wanting to use `IntrinsicWidth` is understandable, because they have a performance hit. But why are you against using `Stack`?

Comment: @user1032613 Red() & Green() may overflow onto Yellow()

Answer (score 0):

their is problem in the Blue(), inside the blue, you should just make the width: double.infinity; and what else problem you got ?

Comment: Sorry I may have confused you, the Blue() has a fixed width(e.g. a long Text() ), so I want the Red(), Yellow(), Green() follow the width of Blue(), and PurpleWrap() also follow the width of Blue()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SizedBox(
        // your blue size
        width: 300,
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Row(children: [
            Container(
                height: 100,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.pink,
                child: Text("Flexible 22222")),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 100,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: const Text("Horizontally center")),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 100, color: Colors.green, child: Text("Flexible")),
          ]),
          Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Fixed Size")),
          Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [Text("Wrap 1")])),
          Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [Text("Wrap 2")])),
        ]),
      )
```

[image: response]

Comment: you can delete all constant values.it will work. I gave it to you to see

Comment: I see. For the Wrap, it literarily a Wrap which may have any no. of row when Blue() or Wrap() children value changed.

Comment: Also, since Red() & Green may have different width, the way you do cannot truly center the Yellow()

Comment: try it. will be precisely centered. Because expanded will fill the remaining space

Comment: if you want the remaining fields to be empty, put spacer() remove expanded